# Unwanted border appearing around subreports when Conditional Formatting applied

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that has conditional formatting applied to change the background of  a row. However, whenever the condition is met, an extra border is also applied around 2 subreports that are a part of the report. An example of that is in the "Active Transcribers" column in the screenshot:

[image]

The 2 shaded rows are those that meet the conditional criteria and the unshaded one does not.

As you can see from my style, I am not doing anything that should impact the border:

```
<style name="Row shading" mode="Transparent" backcolor="#D6D0D0">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[WEEKDAY($F{day} ) == 6 || WEEKDAY($F{day} ) == 7]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#99CCFF">
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try to change expression using parameters? For example: `<conditionExpression><![CDATA[WEEKDAY($P{day} ) == 6]]></conditionExpression>` Does it work?

Comment: @AlexK Thank you for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to help. Whatever expression I use, whenever the criteria is met, the symptoms occur.